# Comparing Answers (Not in Array)

Tags: java, random, comparison

How do you tell Java to print the value of matching numbers that are randomly generated. For example, if the output is 3,3,7: the system should print out, "You got two 3's".

```
    int r1 = (int) (Math.random()*6) +1;
    int r2 = (int) (Math.random()*6) +1;
    int r3 = (int) (Math.random()*6) +1;


    System.out.print("Your numbers are " + r1 + r2 + r3);

    if (r1 == r2 && r2 ==r3 )
        System.out.print(": You got all" + r1 + "'s");
    else if (r1 == r2 || r2 == r3 || r1 == r3)
        System.out.print(": You got two" + "'s");
    else if (r1 != r2 && r2 != r3)
        System.out.print(": NO MATCHES!");
    else {

    }
```

Comment: In your `if` you need to determine which common number it is and assign it to a variable. You already know how to print an integer.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that works with any number of rolls using the `Collections.frequency` method would be:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(roll1, roll2, roll3);
Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>(list);

for (Integer i : set)
{
    System.out.println(i + ": " + Collections.frequency(list, i));
}
```

Convert your rolls to a list, make a set of it (a set does not have duplicate entries).

For every value in the set print how often the value exists in the list. For the rolls `3, 3, 7` this will print:

```
3: 2
7: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You should cleanup your code...

The code you provided does not compile.
The logic seems ok tho.

```
package stackoverflow;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int r1 = (int) (Math.random()*6) +1;
        int r2 = (int) (Math.random()*6) +1;
        int r3 = (int) (Math.random()*6) +1;


        System.out.print("Your numbers are " + r1 + r2 + r3);

        if (r1 == r2 && r2 ==r3 )
            System.out.print(": You got all " + r1 + "'s");
        else if (r1 == r2 || r2 == r3 || r1 == r3)
            System.out.print("numbers: " + r1 + " " + r2 + " " + r3);
        else if (r1 != r2 && r1 != r3) 
            System.out.print(": NO MATCHES!");
        else {

        }
    }
}
```

This should work based on your given code.

Notice that you are naming variables that are not consistent/existing.

Answer (score 1):

Solution: break the random assignment number of two numbers into three parts.

```
int r1 = (int) (Math.random()*6) +1;
int r2 = (int) (Math.random()*6) +1;
int r3 = (int) (Math.random()*6) +1;


System.out.print("Your numbers are " + r1 + r2 + r3);

if (r1 == r2 && r2 ==r3 )
    System.out.print(": You got all" + r1 + "'s");
else if (r1 == r2)
    System.out.print(": You got two" + r1 + "'s");
else if (r2 == r3)
    System.out.print(": You got two" + r2 + "'s");    
else if (r1 == r3)
    System.out.print(": You got two" + r1 + "'s");
else if (r1 != r2 && r2 != r3)
    System.out.print(": NO MATCHES!");
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be

```
    int roll1 = (int) (Math.random()*6) +1;
    int roll2 = (int) (Math.random()*6) +1;
    int roll3 = (int) (Math.random()*6) +1;


    System.out.print("Your numbers are " + roll1 + roll2 + roll3);

    if (roll1 == roll2 && roll2 == roll3 )
        System.out.print(": You got all" + s1 + "'s");
    else if (roll1 == roll2) 
        System.out.print(": You got two" + roll1 + "'s");
    else if (roll2 == roll3)
        System.out.print(": You got two" + roll2 + "'s");
    else if (roll1 == roll3)
        System.out.print(": You got two" + roll1 + "'s");
    else
        System.out.print(": NO MATCHES!");
```

Comment: This outputs in the ```else if``` the following: ```You got two's```